# 301 Redirect Using Wildcards and .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm new to using 301 redirects so I don't know if this is possible, but I want to take part of the old url and use it in the new url using wildcards.

example.com/folder/file.php to

example.com/newfolder/newfolder/file-keyword/

Where the file name is a wildcard and the name of the file (without the .php) is inserted into the new url example.com/newfolder/newfolder/{insert the file name here}-keyword/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a RewriteRule to accomplish this. For example:

# if its going in your [docRoot]/folder/.htaccess:
**RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php http://example.com/newfolder/newfolder/$1-keyword/**

# if its going in your [docRoot]/.htaccess:
**RewriteRule ^folder/(.+)\.php http://example.com/newfolder/newfolder/$1-keyword/**

# if its going in your main config:
**RewriteRule ^/folder/(.+)\.php http://example.com/newfolder/newfolder/$1-keyword/**

This assumes that your rewrite module is loaded in the main config:
**LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so**

And enabled in the same scope you declare your RewriteRule:
**RewriteEngine On**

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!  This worked perfectly!